# PHP to show a specific date format on specific days/times

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to return a date string with a set of rules but am unable to work out how to set it up using http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

All I am trying to do is:

- If it's Tuesday but later than 12:30 pm then show the upcoming Wednesday's date.
- Any time and day before Tuesday 12:30 would show the previous Wednesday's date

Both returns should be in the format of `dd/mm/yyyy` (31/03/2016 for example)

Comment: you should show us what you have tried so far, also probably not use am/pm convention as it's not really internationally used. (and not at all used in php)

Comment: @Jester Indeed, I should but all I have is echoing a date object which is basically nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. Let me know if this will work for you.

```
<?php 

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
date_default_timezone_get();

$timenow = date("H:i"); 
$daynow = date("l");
$time = "12:30";
$day = "Tuesday";
$otherday = array("Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday");


if (($daynow == $day) && ($timenow > $time)) {
    echo "Its's $day $timenow after $time and next $day will be at: "  . date('Y-n-d', strtotime('next Wednesday')) . "" ;
} elseif  (($daynow == $day) && ($timenow < $time)) {
    echo "Its's $day $timenow before $time and last $day was at : "  . date('Y-n-d', strtotime('pevious Wednesday')) . "" ;
} elseif (in_array($daynow, $otherday)) {
    echo "Its's $daynow $timenow before $day $time and last $day was at: "  . date('Y-n-d', strtotime('pevious Wednesday')) . "";
} else {
    echo "Its's $daynow $timenow after $day $time and next $day will be at: "  . date('Y-n-d', strtotime('next Wednesday')) . "";
}

?>
```

Also you could trim some parts away like `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');` or `date_default_timezone_get();` if everything is setup correctly on your server.

Comment: and you can use Jester's code to display the message of the next or previous Wednesday :)

Comment: For the part that is `echo "It's $day before $time"` surely replacing that with echo `date('d/m/Y', strtotime('previous Wednesday'));` would be correct? It returns the incorrect day.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<?php
    echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime('next Wednesday',strtotime("-1 week +11 hours +30 minutes")));
?>
```

edited it, was one hour off i think. here are the 2 test cases:

```
<?php
    echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime('next Wednesday',strtotime("-1 week +11 hours +30 minutes",strtotime('4/5/2016 12:29'))));
    echo PHP_EOL;
    echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime('next Wednesday',strtotime("-1 week +11 hours +30 minutes",strtotime('4/5/2016 12:30'))));
?>
```

Try and read up more on date function and the strtotime/strftime they all have good uses.

Comment: Jester, why does this part `-1 week +11 hours +30 minutes` show 11 hours, 30 mins. What if I wanted to change the time to later than `20:30` would I put that to `-1 week +19 hours +30 minutes`

Comment: correct, also depending on the local time of your server you might have to add or subtract a few hours, or set the timezone first as done in the answer of Niels van Osch. you can easily test whether you have it set up correctly using the last 2 lines